# probability, at least one is not present

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

you have $5$ red balls, $10$ green balls, and $15$ yellow balls in a balls. You randomly choose $5$ without replacement.

What is the probability that at least one of the $3$ colors is not present among the $5$ you pick? Hint: $P(A \cup B \cup C)=$?

attempt:

$P(\text{at least one not present})=1-P(\text{all 3 present})$. Then I got stuck. I expand 
$$
  P( A \cup B \cup C) 
= P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap C)-P(B \cap C) \\
  + P(A \cap B \cap C).
$$
But I got stuck too.

Comment: So you are doing a very silly mistake. You write 1 - all three present . Then you use union . Use intersection for all three balls present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atleast one of the three colors not present =

$P(E)= 1-P(All)
    = 1-P(A \cap B \cap C)$

Now use your formula the other way round.